# rosdep install cv_bridge: failed to install opencv2.3

Tags: ros, debian, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using ROS Electric installed from source under Debian Squeeze. I need to use the package cv_bridge so I installed the stack vision_opencv, which depends on OpenCV2.3.

When I execute *rosdep install cv_bridge*, I get the following error:

```
Failed to find rosdep opencv2.3 for package cv_bridge on OS:debian version:squeeze
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install opencv2.3
```

According to the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Debian):

```
The opencv-2.3 package is not available on squeeze. 
The quicker solution is to get libcv-dev. 
The best solution would be to add a source tarball install in the rosdep.yaml
```

Has anybody implemented that *best solution*?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44909/rosdep-install-cv_bridge:-failed-to-install-opencv2.3/) by [flamenco](https://answers.ros.org/users/944/flamenco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I don't know if this is the best solution, but what I did is to modify the OpenCV2.3 section of vision_opencv/rosdep.yaml

```
opencv2.3:
  ubuntu:
    lucid:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~lucid]
    maverick:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~maverick]
    natty:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~natty]
    oneiric:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~oneiric]
```

For this other

```
opencv2.3:
  ubuntu:
    lucid:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~lucid]
    maverick:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~maverick]
    natty:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~natty]
    oneiric:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv2.3-dev=2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~oneiric]
  debian:
    squeeze: |
      if [ ! -f /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1 ] ; then
        mkdir -p ~/ros/ros-deps
        cd ~/ros/ros-deps
        wget --tries=10 -O OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2/download
        tar xjvf OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2
        cd OpenCV-2.3.1
        mkdir release
        cd release
        cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
        make && sudo make install
        sudo cp /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv-2.3.1.pc
      fi
```

It worked for me, I hope it helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-02**:
Good to know this works for Electric. Unfortunately, it will *not* work for Fuerte or Groovy.